# Получение определенной строки среди результатов группировки

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Необходимый результат от SQL-запроса:

1. Сгруппировать строки
2. Выделить одну из строк внутри каждой группы (например, строку с минимальным ID)
3. Вернуть для выбранных строк некоторые поля, не участвующие в фильтрации в предыдущем пункте

Например, для таблицы `users ( id, birthdate, department_id, ... )` получить ID самого младшего сотрудника в каждом отделе.
В [доках PostgreSQL по аггрегирующим функциям](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-agg.html) похожую проблему решают при помощи вложенных запросов. Для приведенного выше примера выйдет что-то такое:

```
select department_id, min(id) as youngest_user_id
from users users_outer
where birthdate = (
  select max(birthdate)
  from users users_inner
  where users_inner.department_id = users_outer.department_id
)
group by department_id
```

Вопрос: можно ли достичь того же результата, но без использования подзапросов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще без использования подзапросов достичь того же результата нельзя. Ведь над данными действительно нужно проделать две различные операции, которые никак не могут быть сведены к одной, пусть и более сложной, поскольку вторая операция (выбор записи с максимальной `birthdate`) даже для того, чтобы просто начать выполняться для какого-то конкретного `department_id`, уже требует полного завершения первой операции (группировки всех данных по `department_id`).

Довольно легко себе представить алгоритм, посредством которого можно было бы решить данную задачу за один проход. Но это был бы императивный алгоритм, предполагающий сложную работу с данными, непрерывно меняющими своё состояние. На SQL такой алгоритм выразить невозможно, поскольку это декларативный язык запросов, позволяющий описывать лишь желаемый результат.

Тем не менее, в PostgreSQL есть фича, специально предназначенная как раз для таких трюков - Window Functions. Эта фича позволяет описывать так называемые окна, которые по сути представляют собой группы записей без обязательного схлопывания каждой получившейся группы в единственную запись. Исходные записи не заменяются результатом групповой агрегации, а просто дополняются одним или несколькими столбцами, которые содержат результат той или иной агрегирующей функции.

Например, можно пронумеровать строки внутри каждого окна, а во внешнем запросе выбрать только первые по счету записи:

```
select department_id, id as youngest_user_id
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by department_id order by birthdate desc) as num
    from users
) as s
where num = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересная идея! Данный пример выдаст дубли при наличии сотрудников одинакового возраста, но с этим я уже как-нибудь сам разберусь ))

Comment: @СитниковХамелеонЮра Не совсем понял, почему будут дубли. Первая запись в каждом окне будет лишь одна, даже при наличии сотрудников одинакового возраста.